# how to set the background of a jframe to a picture? useing a Jlabel

Tags: java, image, swing, jframe

i Need to create set the Background of my jframe to a picture can anyone help me?
i also have a second class called FolderCreate but it dosent use the frame at all. it is gonna make it so that the layout dosent look bad.

```
/*   Conrad Rowan & Hayley Cummings
 *   Period 6
 *   Address book
 */

//change all the text fields to text areas

import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Container;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Panel;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileWriter;

import javax.swing.AbstractButton;
import javax.swing.DefaultListModel;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JList;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.JTextArea;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ListSelectionListener;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Scanner;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;



public class AddressFinal implements ActionListener, ListSelectionListener{

// The start.

    JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("C/Users/399430/Desktop/eagle.jpg"));




    //JPanels's
    JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    JPanel panel2 = new JPanel();

    String toThings = new String();

    //JFrame's
    JFrame frame = new JFrame();

    //Containers
    Container east = new Container();
    Container south = new Container();
    Container west = new Container();
    Container north = new Container();

    //JButtons
    JButton create = new JButton("Create");
    JButton save = new JButton("Save");

    //The Layout
    GridLayout grid = new GridLayout(3, 1);

    //Text Fields
    JTextArea labelsTF = new JTextArea("Enter in some information in the box to the bottom right, if you'd like!");
    JTextArea finderBarTF = new JTextArea("Type in your new contact name.");
    JTextArea Contact2 = new JTextArea
    ("Last Name: " + "\n" + "\n" +
    "Street address: " + "\n" + "\n" +
    "City: " + "\n" + "\n" +
    "State: " + "\n" + "\n" +
    "ZIP code: " + "\n" + "\n" +
    "Phone number: " + "\n" + "\n" +
    "Extra: " + "\n" + "\n"
    );
    DefaultListModel data = new DefaultListModel();
    JList Contact1;


    FolderCreate folder = new FolderCreate();

    public AddressFinal() {
        Contact2.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 14));
        //data[1] = "george";

        Contact1 = new JList(data); 

        toThings = Contact2.getText();

        panel.setOpaque(false);
//      Set the sizes
        finderBarTF.setSize(50, 60);
        panel.setSize(825, 625);
        frame.setSize(850, 650);
        create.setSize(50, 60);
        Contact1.setSize(100, 60);
        save.setSize(50, 60);
        labelsTF.setSize(50, 60);
        east.setSize(400, 300);
        west.setSize(400, 300);
        frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());

        panel.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
          Contact1.setOpaque(false);  
          save.setOpaque(false);
          save.setContentAreaFilled(false);
          save.setBorderPainted(false);
          create.setOpaque(false);
          create.setContentAreaFilled(false);
          create.setBorderPainted(false);
//      north east south west stuff 
          Contact2.setOpaque(false);
          finderBarTF.setOpaque(false);
          labelsTF.setOpaque(false);

        south.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 2));
        north.setLayout(new GridLayout(2, 2));
        //finderBarTF.addActionListener(this);
        north.add(labelsTF);
        create.addActionListener(this);
        //labelsTF.addActionListener(this);
        save.addActionListener(this);
        south.add(Contact2);

        south.add(Contact1);
        Contact1.addListSelectionListener(this);
        final File folder = new File("contacts");
        listFilesForFolder(folder);
        east.setLayout(grid);
        //south.setLayout(grid);
        north.add(create);
        north.add(finderBarTF);
        north.add(save);
        ((javax.swing.DefaultListCellRenderer)Contact1.getCellRenderer()).setOpaque(false);
        panel.add(south, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        panel.add(north, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel2.add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);
        frame.add(panel);
        //JTextArea.setBackground(Color.RED);

        frame.add(panel2);

        frame.add(east, BorderLayout.EAST);

        north.add(finderBarTF);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        frame.setVisible(true);

        frame.add(myLabel);


    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new AddressFinal();
    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == create ) {

            panel.setBackground(Color.BLUE);
            toThings = Contact2.getText();
            folder.createFile(finderBarTF.getText(), toThings);
            data.addElement(finderBarTF.getText());
        }

        if (e.getSource() == save) {

            toThings = Contact2.getText();
            folder.createFile((String) Contact1.getSelectedValue(), toThings);

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void valueChanged(ListSelectionEvent e) {
        System.out.println(Contact1.getSelectedValue());
        File f = new File("contacts"+File.separator+(String) Contact1.getSelectedValue());
        Scanner s;
        try {
            s = new Scanner(f);
            String input = "";
                    while (s.hasNext()){
                    input = input + s.nextLine();
                    input = input + "\n";
                    }
            s.close();
            Contact2.setText(input);
        } catch (FileNotFoundException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

        public void listFilesForFolder(final File folder) {
            for (final File fileEntry : folder.listFiles()) {
                if (fileEntry.isDirectory()) {
                    listFilesForFolder(fileEntry);
                } else {
                    //System.out.println(fileEntry.getName());
                    data.addElement(fileEntry.getName());
                }
            }
        }




}
```

Comment: Just how many duplicates of this question are there?!

Answer (score 0):

Setting the background of a JFrame, to my knowledge, is not possible, however, you can set the image inside of a label, and then use the label as the image.

```
JLabel myLabel = new JLabel(new ImageIcon("/path/to/file.jpg"));
```